# GitHub for .NET application on Windows?

Tags: .net, version-control, github

I am an old time [Visual SourceSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) developer but now I want to change the route. I heard about [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). Does anybody use GitHub on Windows for [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) applications? What is your take? What are all the bug tracking systems we can use with GitHub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git is definitely a different beast than SourceSafe, so make sure you read up on its philosphy before trying to do much of anything.  In particular, I recommend [Git Magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/).

You don't have to use github to use git, and in fact, many people don't.  It's an incredibly cool tool, but it'll be mostly useful to you if you're developing OSS.  Otherwise, the whole social aspect will be lost on you.

I don't see why should be limited in what issue tracker you use with git; you create an issue, fix the code, and resolve the issue.  That said, github has basic issue tracking built in, if you don't feel like using something a little more advanced.  There is also [ticgit](http://wiki.github.com/schacon/ticgit), which stores your tickets in a branch in your repository and provides a ruby-powered cli interface to them.  Pretty cool, but probably not your thing, if you're a Windows developer.

You may also want to take a look at [Why Git is Better Than X](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/), a site that attempts to convince you of the superiority of git over mercurial, bazaar, subversion and perforce.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub makes using Git very nice, I use the Git Extensions for Visual Studio. http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/ Git is a Version Control System, but it doesn't do bug tracking to my knowledge. Git/GitHub DO have the ability to fire events when certain things happen (hooks). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[There is now a GitHub for Windows that should make this a lot easier.](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows)